# Resolve deferred object after other multiple deferred objects are resolved

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

My experience with `$.Deferred` is very limited, and so far the code the came looks very messy.

The function that is supposed to return a promise is updating the DOM with HTML received after an ajax request.

It's used like this:

```
this._refreshWorkspace(response.html).then(function(){
  // do things after DOM update finished
});
```

Here's the function code:

```
_refreshWorkspace: function(htmlBlocks){

  var dfd = $.Deferred();

  if('editor' in htmlBlocks){
    app.destroy(this.editor).then((function(){
      this.editor.empty().append(htmlBlocks.editor);
    }).bind(this)).then((function(){
      app.refresh(this.editor);
    }).bind(this));
  }

  if('listPanels' in htmlBlocks){
    app.destroy(this.list).then((function(){
      this.list.empty().append(htmlBlocks.listPanels);
    }).bind(this)).then((function(){
      app.refresh(this.list);
      // other unrelated code here
      dfd.resolve();

    }).bind(this));
  }

  if('listNav' in htmlBlocks){
    // similar code block       
  }

  return dfd;
},
```

It seems to work but only if the "listPanels" htmlBlock is provided.
I want the `dfd` to be resolved once after all refresh calls, or even better if possible - after all refresh calls are resolved. Any ideas on how could I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all of the promises from the loops into an array, then use [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/). Sadly, using `$.when` with an array is ugly:

```
return $.when.apply($, theArray);
```

...because `$.when` is designed to accept discrete arguments rather than an array.

Something like this:

```
_refreshWorkspace: function(htmlBlocks){

  var promises = [];

  if('editor' in htmlBlocks){
    promises.push(
      app.destroy(this.editor).then((function(){
        this.editor.empty().append(htmlBlocks.editor);
      }).bind(this)).then((function(){
        app.refresh(this.editor);
      }).bind(this))
    );
  }

  if('listPanels' in htmlBlocks){
    promises.push(
      app.destroy(this.list).then((function(){
        this.list.empty().append(htmlBlocks.listPanels);
      }).bind(this)).then((function(){
        app.refresh(this.list);
      }).bind(this))
    );
  }

  if('listNav' in htmlBlocks){
    // similar code block       
  }

  return $.when.apply($, promises);
},
```

Here's a live example using random `Deferred`s:

```js
function doSomething() {
  var promises = [];
  var d1, d2, d3;
  
  d1 = new $.Deferred();
  promises.push(d1.promise());
  setTimeout(function() {
    snippet.log("Resolving d1");
    d1.resolve(1);
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
  
  d2 = new $.Deferred();
  promises.push(d2.promise());
  setTimeout(function() {
    snippet.log("Resolving d2");
    d2.resolve(2);
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
  
  d3 = new $.Deferred();
  promises.push(d3.promise());
  setTimeout(function() {
    snippet.log("Resolving d3");
    d3.resolve(3);
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
  
  return $.when.apply($, promises);
}

// Use it
doSomething().then(function() {
  snippet.log("All resolved");
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As already explained, the simple answer to the question is to aggregate the individual promises with `$.when.apply(null, promiseArray)`.

However, if all the code in the question is representative of the treatment to be applied to all html blocks, then you can go further.

`jQuery.map()` will operate on ownProperties of an object so can be exploited to iterate over `htmlBlocks`, resulting in a concise, generalised main routine with a couple of supporting hashes.

```
_refreshWorkspace: function(htmlBlocks) {
    var that = this; // avoids the need for .bind(this) in the promise chain and the methodsHash
    var propHash = {
        'editor': 'editor',
        'listPanels': 'list'
    };
    // All the "other unrelated code" is defined here
    var methodsHash = {
        'editor': null,
        'listPanels': function(key, obj) {
            ...
        },
        ...
    };
    //And the main routine is a concise $.map(htmlBlocks, ...) structure. 
    var promises = $.map(htmlBlocks, function(html, key) {
        var obj = that[propHash[key]];
        return app.destroy(obj).then(function() {
            obj.empty().append(html); //if empty() and append() are jQuery methods then this line is synchronous.
            return app.refresh(obj);// if app.destroy() is asynch and theanable, then it seems safe to assume that app.refresh() is also asynch and theanable. Therefore return the result here.
        }).then(function() {
            if(methodsHash[key]) {
                methodsHash[key](key, obj);
            }
        });
    });

    //Now aggregate `promises` into a single promise which resolves when all the promises resolve, or rejects when any of the promises rejects.
    return $.when.apply(null, promises);
},
```

Now, to cater for all other html blocks, just add one line to `propHash` and a null or function to `methodsHash`. Providing the main routine is comprehensive, it won't need amending.

IMHO, this a better way to organise the code.